# MUI Autocomplete with "group" options

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use the MUI Autocomplete component (with multiple values) to select a list of users. In the list of options, I have some Users and some UserGroups.
When I click on a UserGroup, I want
(a) every member of that group to be added to the selection individually,
(b) the newly added members should be filtered from the options list
(c) the group itself should also be filtered from the options

(a) works, but I'm having trouble with <del>(b) and</del> (c). Furthermore, when I click on a UserGroup, the suggestions list stays open, I would like it to close, just like after clicking on a User (d).

Is this possible / am I approaching this completely wrong?

This is my code so far:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Autocomplete, Button, Dialog, TextField } from '@mui/material'

export interface User {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    email: string,
    isGroup: boolean
}

export interface UserGroup
{
    id: string,
    name: string,
    users: User[],
    isGroup: boolean,
}

export interface ExampleDialogProps {
    users: User[];
    userGroups: UserGroup[];
}

const ExampleDialog = ({ users, userGroups,}: ExampleDialogProps): JSX.Element => {

    const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState<any[]>([]);

    const renderOption = (props, option) => {
        if (option.isGroup) {
          return (
            <li {...props} onClick={() => {setSelectedUsers([...selectedUsers, ...option.users]);}}>
              {option.name}
            </li>
          );
        }
        return <li {...props} > {option.name}</li>;
      };

    return (
        <Dialog open={true} fullWidth>
            <Autocomplete
                multiple
                value={selectedUsers}
                options={[...users, ...userGroups]}
                getOptionLabel={(option)=>option.name}
                filterSelectedOptions
                onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                    console.log(newValue)
                    setSelectedUsers(newValue);
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => (<TextField {...params}/> )}
                renderOption={renderOption}
            />
            <Button onClick={() => console.log(selectedUsers)}>Close</Button>
        </Dialog>
    )
}

export default ExampleDialog
```

Edit: I was able to solve (b) by providing a custom isOptionEqualToValue prop:

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option,value)=>option.id===value.id}
```

The issue (or part of it) seems to be that with the custom onClick event I defined for my group options, the Autocomplete component's onChange handler doesn't trigger, even though the value prop does change.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve all the issues above, this is my final code:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Autocomplete, Button, Dialog, TextField, createFilterOptions } from '@mui/material'

export interface User {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    email: string,
    isGroup: boolean
}

export interface UserGroup
{
    id: string,
    name: string,
    users: User[],
    isGroup: boolean,
}

export interface ExampleDialogProps {
    users: User[];
    userGroups: UserGroup[];
}

function filterGroups(options: (User | UserGroup)[], selectedUsers: User[]): (User | UserGroup)[] 
{
    return options.filter(option => {
        if (!option.isGroup) return true;
        const group = option as UserGroup;
        return group.users.some((user) => !selectedUsers.map(u => u.id).includes(user.id));
    });
}
const searchFn = createFilterOptions<User | UserGroup>();

const ExampleDialog = ({ users, userGroups}: ExampleDialogProps): JSX.Element => {

    const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);
    const [listboxOpen, setListboxOpen] = useState(false);
    
    const handleCloseListbox = () => {
        setListboxOpen(false);
    };

    const handleOpenListbox = () => {
        setListboxOpen(true);
    };

    const renderOption = (props, option) => {
        if (option.isGroup) {
            return (
                <li 
                    {...props} 
                    onClick={(e) => {
                        // since we are using a custom onClick handler, we need to close the options list manually
                        setListboxOpen(false);
                        
                        //don't want to add group members who are already included in the selection
                        const newUsers = option.users.filter((user: User)=>!selectedUsers.map(u=>u.id).includes(user.id)) 
                        setSelectedUsers([...selectedUsers, ...newUsers]);
                    }}
                >
                    {option.name}
                </li>
            );
        }
        return <li {...props}> {option.name} </li>;
      };

    return (
        <Dialog open={true} fullWidth>
            <Autocomplete
                multiple
                open={listboxOpen}
                value={selectedUsers}
                options={[...users, ...userGroups]}
                getOptionLabel={(option)=>option.name}
                filterSelectedOptions
                onOpen={handleOpenListbox}
                onClose={handleCloseListbox}
                onChange={(event, newValue) => { setSelectedUsers(newValue as User[]); }}
                filterOptions={(options, state)=>{
                    // first, do the default filtering based on user input
                    const filteredOptions = searchFn(options, state);
                    // then also filter out groups whose members are already selected
                    return filterGroups(filteredOptions, selectedUsers);
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => (<TextField {...params}/> )}
                renderOption={renderOption}
                isOptionEqualToValue={(option,value)=>option.id===value.id}
            />
            <Button onClick={() => console.log(selectedUsers)}>Close</Button>
        </Dialog>
    )
}

export default ExampleDialog
```